# Can't bundle with py2xe, keeps wanting to include tkinter though it is not used

Tags: python, tkinter, console, bundle, py2exe

py2exe's been driving me insane.

I'm trying to bundle a small app that has no GUI or anything and even though I am not using TKinter, py2exe keeps wanting to bundle it in the .exe.

I'm a beginner in all this so if the my app code is not that great, that's the reason.

Below is my code

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os
file_types = ("*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.tif", "*.tiff", "*.png", "*.bmp")

image_list = []

for images in file_types :
    image_list.extend(glob.glob(images))

maxW = 1920
maxH = 1920

def ResizeImages(image_list) :
    if not os.path.exists("done") :
        os.makedirs("done")

    for image in image_list :
        img = Image.open(image)
        imgnoext = os.path.splitext(image)[0]
        width = img.size[0]
        height = img.size[1]
        ratio = float(width) / float(height)
        if width > maxW :
            height = int(maxW / ratio)
            resized = img.resize((maxW,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            resized.save("done/" + imgnoext + ".jpg", format="JPEG", quality=90)
        elif height > maxH :
            width = int(maxW * ratio)
            resized = img.resize((width,maxH), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            resized.save("done/" + imgnoext + ".jpg", format="JPEG", quality=90)
        else :
            img.save("done/" + imgnoext + ".jpg", format="JPEG", quality=90)

ResizeImages(image_list)
```

And this is the setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {
        'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    console = [{'script': "resize.py"}],
    zipfile = None
)
```

And every time I try to bundle it, this happens:

```
running py2exe

  11 missing Modules                 
  ------------------                 
? PIL._imagingagg                     imported from PIL.ImageDraw
? PyQt4                               imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PyQt5                               imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PySide                              imported from PIL.ImageQt
? _grabscreen                         imported from PIL.ImageGrab
? _imaging_gif                        imported from PIL.GifImagePlugin
? _util                               imported from PIL.ImageCms
? cffi                                imported from PIL.Image, PIL.PyAccess
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
OOPS: tkinter 2
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to bundle this so that it will run on any Windows machine, with or without Python installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried and tried, and was not able to bundle this using py2exe.

If someone else runs into this problem, just use PyInstaller. It worked the first time, with no issues.